# Create a namespace with resource quota in one go

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to combine a namespace creation with a resource quota in one go? 
I'm looking for something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
    name: custom-namespace
quota: {"cpu": "400m", "memory": "1Gi"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine different documents in the same YAML file using dashes as separator.

For your example it would like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
    name: custom-namespace
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: cpu
  namespace: custom-namespace
spec:
  hard:
    limits.cpu: "400m"
    limits.memory: 1Gi
```

You can then apply the file or pipe it from stdin.

```
$ kubectl apply -f temp.yaml 
namespace/custom-namespace created
resourcequota/cpu created
```